# Vue3 Composition: Dynamic default element class on runtime

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to find a better way to provide a default style(such as class name) to my elements, which are being used all around the app, by the style returned from the server and accessible via vuex store. Ive worked around by using provide/inject to provide these styles after fetching from the server, but I still think there's a better way to do this.
So anyone who has the solution, please leave your idea below, many thanks.

```js
// In root component
defineComponent({
  setup(){
     provide('class-key', className);
  }
});

// In child elements
defineComponent({
  setup(){
     inject('class-key', '');
  }
});
```

Comment: You could use it from Vuex. You'd need provide/inject if there were no Vuex or a value could change depending on a tree of components

Comment: You can just use the value directly from the vuex state if it's already in there.  No need for provide/inject.

Comment: thanks guys, i think i made it complicated